# Setting multiple breakpoints at once in MSVS 2010

Tags: c++, debugging

I have cpp code where I want to put the break points inside every `if` statement and every `else` statement at once without going into them individually. How can I do this? Any tips or tricks?
Ehhmm I am using the Express Edition 2010.
Please suggest! 
Rgds,
softy

Comment: Why in every if statement? Set a breakpoint and stepping through is typically what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Create Visual Studio Macro. The following [procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) steps through creating an example of a simple macro.